# change register url on wp-login page

Tags: wp-login-form

I am just trying to change the url of "register" on wp default login page(domain.com/wp-login.php)

1. I want to change the url on register link.
2. when you are on domain.com/wp-login.php?action=register, I want to redirect to domain.com/register

I have added redirect link. but it's not working.

```
 RedirectMatch 301 /wp-login.php?action=register$ http://domain.com/register/$1
```

Am I missing something?

I just want to use my register page (domain.com/register/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code from @bainternet's [website](http://en.bainternet.info/2012/wordpress-easy-login-url-with-no-htaccess).

```
function wpse127636_register_url($link){
    /*
        Change wp registration url
    */
    return str_replace(site_url('wp-login.php?action=register', 'login'),site_url('register', 'login'),$link);
}
add_filter('register','wpse127636_register_url');

function wpse127636_fix_register_urls($url, $path, $orig_scheme){
    /*
        Site URL hack to overwrite register url     
        http://en.bainternet.info/2012/wordpress-easy-login-url-with-no-htaccess
    */
    if ($orig_scheme !== 'login')
        return $url;

    if ($path == 'wp-login.php?action=register')
        return site_url('register', 'login');

    return $url;
}
add_filter('site_url', 'wpse127636_fix_register_urls', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 5):

Put this code in your Theme's "functions.php" file.
Replace the page ID  with where it says [REPLACE WITH YOUR PAGE ID HERE].

```
/* start  */ 
add_filter( 'register_url', 'custom_register_url' );
function custom_register_url( $register_url )
{
    $register_url = get_permalink( $register_page_id = [REPLACE WITH YOUR PAGE ID HERE] );
    return $register_url;
}
/* end */
```

Comment: Add some explanation saying how this code fits for the Question.

Comment: No it's not working I added post id but when I go to /wp-login, it doesn't redirect. anyway thank you.

Comment: It should work if dont correctly. 
did you add the numerical value of the page, to which you want to redirect?
PS: you don't need to edit or change anything on the wp-login.php file itself. Just add this code in the functions.php file will do.

Comment: It does work. Thank you!

Comment: It’s probably obvious to most but don’t include the square brackets :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the register_url filter

```
add_filter( 'register_url', 'change_my_register_url' );
    function change_my_register_url( $url ) {
        if( is_admin() ) {
            return $url;
        }
        return "/custom-register-url/";
    }
```

Comment: Why the is_admin() exception? (I'm just curious, I could believe it's right)